# Trying to empty all options except for first option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select and I need to reset the values in it when an item is deleted instead of refreshing the page. The default option keeps getting deleted.

HMTL:

```
<select id="my_SiteGroups" style="width:200px;">
  <option value='default' disabled="disabled">Select a group</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
group = $('#my_SiteGroups');   
function populateGroups(){ 
  //Populate the group list  
  strHTMLSiteGroups = "";
  group.empty(':not(:first-child)');
  $().SPServices({
      operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromSite",
      async: true,
      completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
        $(xData.responseXML).find("Group").each(function() {
        strHTMLSiteGroups += "<option value='" + $(this).attr("Name") + "'>" + $(this).attr("Name") + "</option>";
      });
        group.append(strHTMLSiteGroups);
      }
  });
}
```

Basically the populateGroups added all the  to the select but when I delete users, I want it to run again. To remove the option that was deleted. I use this to delete:

```
function removeGroupFromSite(){
  //check if default group selected
  if(group.val() != null){
    var removeConfirm = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete: " + group.val());
    if(removeConfirm){
      $().SPServices({
        operation:"RemoveGroup",
        groupName: groupValue,
        async:true,
        completefunc: function (xData,Status){
           alert(groupValue + " succesfully deleted");          
           group.val('default');
           populateGroups();
          $("#my_SPUsersAssigned").empty();
          $("#my_SPUsersAvailable").empty();
        }
      });
    }
  }else{
    alert("Please select a group");
  }}
```

EDIT: Would it be easier to just append the default option using Javasript?

Comment: You forgot to tell what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry, the problem is that the first option keeps getting deleted.

Answer (score 1):

`empty()` removes all the content, select the options and remove them.

```
$("#my_SiteGroups option:gt(0)").remove();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m2b2K/)

Comment: Is there anything I could do to the groups variable instead of re-grabbing the element?

Comment: Use find? `group.find("option:gt(0)").remove();`

Comment: The "Select a group" should still be there, my fiddle works...What did you do exactly?

Comment: It works if I use your answer but not when using the find function